# Can't do a full mac hard drive clone because of input/output errors

Tags: mac, hard-drive, backup

I do a nightly [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/) clone on my MacBook Pro. Ever since updating to their latest (Lion-compatible) version, it won't do a full clone, but the logs report copy failures because of Input/Output errors. (Unfortuantely, the previous version successfully completed clones, but did not report the errors and simply did not copy the files).

Sure enough, if I try to copy the files it reports, in the Finder or via command line, it also fails. Every time I delete one of these offending files, and try to run a new clone, it finds another file that can't be copied (this has happened three times so far).

Obviously I'm thinking this hard drive is ready to crash, but is there a way to verify? Disk Utility reports no problems.

Comment: If this problem started after upgrading SuperDuper!, I'd contact their support people about it.  Try downgrading to the previous version first, to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Check the SMART status of the drive for hints as to whether or not the drive's really in trouble..?

Comment: @Eric - I did contact them and downgrade, and as I mentioned, the clones complete, but the troublesome files simply don't copy. Support wasn't super helpful, just noted that newer versions can be more comprehensive.

Comment: @The White Phoenix - SMART status = verified

Comment: SMART status reporting isn't very reliable; I've seen obviously failing drives (incl. one that sounded like a coffee grinder) that showed  SMART status = verified.  Other tools (like [SMARTReporter](http://www.corecode.at/smartreporter/), [smartctl](http://sixtyfive.xmghosting.com/products/smartctl/), or [Smart Utility](http://www.volitans-software.com/smart_utility.php)) may be able to get more status details.  My advice: freeze the current backup (to avoid backing up more damaged files), get a new drive, and migrate NOW.